# How do I turn off "comment is required" when leaving a rating on a product in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and I allow comments on each product. The Star rating is included. In the woocommerce settings > products > reviews the box for "ratings are required to leave a review" is NOT checked. But, when testing and submitting a rating I get the message that a comment is required. Is there a way to turn this off that I'm missing? 
If I turn off allow comments on each product than ratings are also turned off.

Answer (score 7):

```
add_filter('allow_empty_comment', '__return_true');
```

Comment: You can easily put this sort of thing into your site using the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin. No longer do you need to mess with your functions.php file.

Comment: What about performance?

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this hook, place it in your theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = false;
     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the suggestion. I tried that. I'm using a child theme so I placed it in the functions.php file in my child theme. But it didn't change anything. I still get the error, please add a comment.

The hook you suggested seems to be for the checkout fields and the orders. Would it be the same for the single product page too? I mean would the fields be the same?

Comment: Do you mean the reviews tab on the single page product?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. That's what I mean. I want them to be able to rate a product on the single product page without having to leave a comment. Just click on the star rating and submit.

Comment: If the field is not required maybe you can just hide it using css?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be required even though I've checked the settings in woo commerce to allow ratings without the need for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

For those who didn't find the solution:

```
add_filter('allow_empty_comment', '__return_true');//for Wordpress back-end check
function vahid_wp_footer() {
?>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    var comment = $('textarea#comment');
    comment.removeAttr('required'); // remove required of the text area      
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'vahid_wp_footer' );
```